# Entity Framework. Foreign key references item that doesn't exist

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting null object reference exception error on Export to Excel File.
Problem is that one record has foreign in database that does not have item in other table. I can't change database.

```
if (item.ShipperId != null)
     {         
         str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + item.Shipper.ShipperName + "" + "</font></td>");
     } 
     else
     {
         str.Append("<td><font face=Arial Narrow size=" + "14px" + ">" + "" + "</font></td>");
     }
}
```

ShipperId is Foreign key which is invalid in this case. it gives exception on

```
item.Shipper.ShipperName
```

I have tried checking if it's null

```
if (item.Shipper.ShipperName != null)
```

but it also gives exception on this null check

Comment: if(item.ShipperId>0){ here the code}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference `Shipper` is null. And not the `ShipperName`

Please check `if (item.Shipper != null)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40394900/4949005) from [Ashok M. Prajapati](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6306153/ashok-m-prajapati) your `Shipper`-property is `null`. But since `ShipperId` isn't null it means that the Shipper actually exists in the DB.

> ShipperId is Foreign key which is invalid in this case.

I do not believe this is the case. Since it's not null the SQL Server will make sure that the key exists in the Shipper-table. Since a [foreign key is a constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) the database will not allow you to remove an item if it has a foreign key to it. So if the foreign key is properly configured **you will never** have a key that **doesn't** point to an actual item in another table.

So what you need to do is to *include* it when you fetch your entity, or allow *lazy loading*.

**1. Fetch when loading entity.**
By using [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) you can fetch navigation-properties.

```
var item = context.Items.Include(x => x.Shipper).FirstOrDefault();
```

**2. Using Lazy-loading.**
If you're still in the context, you can use lazy loading. Like [explained in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public BloggingContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```